Proving linear independence of solutions to homogeneuous linear ODE with constant coefficients
I want to prove that the set of functions
$$\{x^ie^{rx}|r\text{ is a root of characteristic polynomial}; 0\le i\le m_r -1\}$$
which are solutions to the differential equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}\cdot y^{(i)}=0\qquad ;\ a_{n}\ne 0 $$
is linearly independent on any arbitrary interval.
If the multiplicity of each root is $1$ , then I am able to do this using the Wronskian and Vandermonde matrix but I have no idea how to prove the general case where multiplicities may exceed $1$.
I would appreciate any hints on how to go about proving this
